# visibility hidden, javascript?

Tags: javascript, visibility

Can someone please tell me why my code isn't working correct, can't seem to figure out why, it's a really simple thing so I don't understand why I can't find the problem...

```
var pictures = document.getElementById('contents').getElementsByClassName('pictureSmall');
    for(k=0; k<pictures.length; k++){ 
        pictures[k].onclick = showPic;
        pictures[k].onblur = hidePic;
    }

function showPic(){
        var showPicture = this.getElementsByClassName('pictureBig')[0];
        showPicture.style.visibility = 'visible';

}

function hidePic(){
        var showPicture = this.getElementsByClassName('pictureBig')[0];
        showPicture.style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

this is the html:

```
    <div id="contents">
            <div class="pictureBig"><img src="bilder/boards.jpg" alt="cruisers"/></div>
        <div id="main" class="content">

            <img src="bilder/miniboardm.jpg" alt="minicruiser" id="boardsprice"/>
            <img src="bilder/miniboard2m.jpg" alt="minicruiser" id="boardgreen"/>
            <img class="pictureSmall" src="bilder/boardssmall.jpg" alt="minicruisers" id="boardsmall"/>
            <img class="pictureSmall" src="bilder/boardbluesmall.jpg" alt="shirt" id="small"/><div class="pictureBig"><img src="bilder/boards.jpg" alt="minicruisers"/></div>
            <img class="pictureSmall" src="bilder/postersmall.jpg" alt="minicruiser" id="small2"/><div class="pictureBig"><img src="bilder/boards.jpg" alt="minicruisers"/></div>
            <img src="bilder/boardcarving.jpg" alt="print" id="boardprint"/>
            <p></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
.pictureBig {
    position:absolute; 
    display:none; 
    background-color:#EEE; 
    border:2px ridge #333; 
    padding:6px; 
    left:10px; 
    z-index:2; 
    margin-left:350px;
}
```

the message I get when I try to display the big picture is "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

Comment: Could you use chrome or firefox debugger? With Firefox you can install the Firebug plugin. Press F12 to see the console and it'll show you the line the error occurred. In your code you can use console.log(something); to see if your variables have the expected value.

Comment: it means that JavaScript is not able to figure out what you mean by `this.getElementsByClassName('pictureBig')[0];`

Comment: you can try jquery for this it so simple to implement

Comment: try adding style tag in img <img src="bilder/miniboardm.jpg" alt="minicruiser" id="boardsprice" style="visibility:hidden"/>

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
var showPicture = document.getElementsByClassName("pictureBig")[0];
```

Comment: The issue relates to Javascript scoping.  The 'this' in the showPic function relates to the pictureSmall element clicked and this obviously will not contain a child element with a class name of pictureBig.  Changing 'this' to 'document' as Jonathan suggests will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` is not supported in all Browsers. You should instead use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` which works in almost all Browsers including IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function showPic(){
        var showPicture = this.
          parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('pictureBig')[0];
        showPicture.style.visibility = 'visible';

}

function hidePic(){
        var showPicture = this.
          parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('pictureBig')[0];
        showPicture.style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding style attribute in img tag as below

```
    <img src="bilder/miniboardm.jpg" alt="minicruiser" 
id="boardsprice" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```